# select just the enum names in Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, intellij-14

Is there any way to select just the enum names using Intellij Idea?

```
...

public enum OrganizationActivityLogItemType implements IActivityLogItemType<OrganizationActivityLog>, DisplaysAs
{

    @Deprecated GENE_VARIANT_PUBLIC( "Gene Variant/Mutation/Allele", null ),

    VARIANTS_MUTATIONS( "Variants/Mutations/ Alleles/Loci/Probes", ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
    CATEGORIES( "Categories", null ),
    PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_COVERED_WHEN_MEETS_NECESSITY_CRITERIA( "Covered - When Meets Medical Necessity Criteria",
                                                            ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
    PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_NOT_COVERED_INVESTIGATIONAL(
        "Not Covered - Investigational",
        ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
    PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_NOT_COVERED_NOT_MEDICALLY_NECESSARY(
        "Not Covered - Not Medically Necessary",
        ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
...
```

Comment: select just the enum names means?

Comment: `PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_NOT_COVERED_NOT_MEDICALLY_NECESSARY` is an enum name.... I want to select all of them for copying, but not the junk in the constructors

Answer (score 1):

Enums in Java are a special class that extend the abstract class `java.lang.Enum` and thus inherits the methods defined there.You can use `name()` method to get the name of your enum constant

[name() method in Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name())

```
OrganizationActivityLogItemType [] enumArray = OrganizationActivityLogItemType.values();
       for(OrganizationActivityLogItemType enumObject: enumArray ){
         System.out.println(enumObject.name());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close

1. open Find dialog
2. click checkboxes for 'Match Case' and 'Regex'
3. use the following regex pattern: [A-Z_]+(?=\()
4. use key command to select all occurrences: Shift + Ctrl + Alt + J (Ctrl + Cmd + G for Mac OS X)
5. copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

Double click on each enum name with <kbd>Alt</kbd> held down.